# VSCode - missing option "Attach Visual Studio Code"

Tags: macos, docker, visual-studio-code

Usually I use the option "Attach Visual Studio Code" to attach VSCode to a Docker container I start from command line.

Today I updated to VSCode version 1.57 and now I can't find the option anymore. Even after installing the previous version 1.56 the option is missing. The only options available are the following from the screen shot.
[image]

The system I am currently using is MacOS 10.15.7, Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350 and the above mentioned VSCode versions.

Does someone know where this is coming from and how to solve the problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reinstalling the VSCode extension "Remote Containers" the option shows up again.

Comment: Test "Remote Development" extension too.

Comment: Now its "Dev Containers".

Answer (score 0):

I created a configuration in launch.json called "debug python on docker" as described here. I also had to make some changes for my python docker-compose.debug.yml file to open the debug listening port and install the python debugger on the container after running, and the Dockerfile to allow for Entrypoint /bin/sh...

Then I started docker-compose.debug.yml and F5 on the configuration "debug python on docker", and I was able to run the code.

so that breakpoint work I had to map the src code folder to the src code folder on the container...

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will definitely try this out.